# Can you post to multiple social networks at the same time with Social Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud

i've been reading the Social Studio documentation looking for an answer, but it doesn't seem like this is possible. 
Is it correct that only one post can be created per social network and then by sharing and re-using the content you can select a different social network?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can post to multiple social networks at the same time in Social Studio with the
"**publishing macro**".

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ss_macros.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, using the Duplicate option.
Duplicating content is used to make a copy of content to repost to a different social network or account in the same workspace.
You can find a tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qI3tLMmdMkw

Best,
Maria Marlene Pereira